# How to extract single dictionary entry?

Tags: python, dictionary

This should be really simple but I can't figure it out.  How do I extract the details for Stu?  So I want to see Name: Stu, Age:14, Weight: 99.5

```
pets_2 = {'Name': {'Molly', 'Stu', 'Henry'},
          'Age':{10, 14, 2},
          'Weight':{101, 99.5, 90.3}}
```

Side-question, is this the correct format to store this type of dictionary?

Comment: You currently have a `dict` with three keys, `'Name'`, `'Age'`, and `'Weight'`. The values to these keys are all `set` objects, which are inherently unordered. This is almost certainly not the correct data-structure to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a structure like this

```
pets_2 = {
    'pet1': {'Name':'Molly', 'Age': 10, 'Weight': 101.0},
    'pet2': {'Name':'Stu', 'Age': 14, 'Weight': 99.5},
    'pet3': {'Name':'Henry', 'Age': 2, 'Weight': 90.3}
}
```

and as far as the getting the data out

```
print(pets_2['pet1']) #{'Name': 'Molly', 'Age': 10, 'Weight': 101.0}
print(pets_2['pet1']['Name']) # Molly
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your values are all **[`sets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)**, so you basically have no way to fetch a specific value. Switch these to a a list, and given you know Stu is the second person, you can assemble Stu:

```
def get_pet(i):
    return {'Name': pets_2['Name'][i],
            'Age': pets_2['Age'][i],
            'Weight': pets_2['Weight'][i]}
```

More naturally, you could just store your data like so:

```
pets_3 = {
    'Stu': {'Age': 14, 'Weight': 99.5},
    # ...
}
```

So getting Stu's info becomes `pets_3['Stu']`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, `set` is unordered. Here is one solution using lists.

```
d = {'Name':   ['Molly', 'Stu', 'Henry'],
     'Age':    [10, 14, 2],
     'Weight': [101, 99.5, 90.3]}

d2 = {d['Name'][i]: (d['Age'][i], d['Weight'][i]) for i in range(len(d))}
# {'Henry': (2, 90.3), 'Molly': (10, 101), 'Stu': (14, 99.5)}

d2['Stu']  # (14, 99.5)
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining to me, makes sense